# How i can get connection string inside migration

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need get connection string inside method `Up()`, and I need get data from a database inside migration. How can I do this?

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
   ....this...
}
```

Or how can I get result from `migrationBuilder.Sql()`?